# Removing lock file from hive metastore database

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am getting the following error in hive database:

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/usr/metastore_db
```

I've heard I can solve it with removing lock file - how safe is this? There's `db.lck` file inside `metastore_db` folder, it contains one line containing some ID string.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can delete that lck file. it just creates id for that derby instance.

also note if you change your local directory and then start hive , you will see another metastore_db directory created with lck file, but all your previous data will be their on your first metastore_db not the new one

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can delete that file. It wont affect your hive. It is just a lock that has been created for that particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the "metastore_db" folder, there will be 2 ".lck" files. Just delete them.  "rm -r *.lck" - You can also start the derby in server mode, to avoid this, or mysql is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the `metastore_db` folder probably in the home folder and delete the `dbex.lck`

If its not there check the `derby.log` to see where the `metastore_db` location is mentioned

It will be created next time when you execute the spark-shell instance